# How to open the Network>headers window of the browser?

Tags: browser, http-headers, developer-tools

I accidentally closed the headers window from Network>headers and I can't open it again.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sy7A.png)
I appreciate advice on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click and select "Inspect" to open Developer tools window. Select the "Network" tab,and then refresh the website. After the website is refreshed, select any address on the left of the Developer Tools and you can see Http Headers ​​​​​​​information.

Comment: It was so simple . . . thanks a lot for taking the time to answer!!